# How to deal with variable scope issues

Tags: c#, asp.net

the variable "doc" is not accessible anywhere else in the method outside of the if statement so that if doc==null fails since the scope of "doc" is only within those if statements that it is defined in....How do I deal with this issue? adding public just leads to more errors..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string id, type, UniqueColID;
            string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~").ToString();
            type = Request.QueryString["type"];

            if (type.Equals("template"))
            {
                MergeDocument template = new MergeDocument(FilePath + @"\Template\MVCTemplate.pdf");
                template.DrawToWeb();
            }
            else
            {
                id = Request.QueryString["id"];
                UniqueColID = DBFunctions.DBFunctions.testExist(id);
                if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == false)
                {
                    MergeDocument doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDF(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
                }
                else if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == true)
                {
                    MergeDocument doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDFDriverOnly(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
                }
                DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly = false;
                    if (doc == null)
                    doc = new MergeDocument(FilePath + @"\Template\MVCTemplate.pdf");

                doc.DrawToWeb();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox("Creating PDF file was not successful. " + err.ToString());
        }
```

I have tried declaring it at higher level but I still get same error:

```
**Use of unassigned local variable 'doc' -->>>at: if (doc==nul)**
```

After doing MergeDocument=null; at higher level I get a new error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at GeneratePDF.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

this error points to `"if (type.Equals("template"))"`

Comment: Declarnng doc at a higher level? E.g. at top "else" statement, before id = Request.QueryString["id"];

Comment: @Nadal - If you tried something else you should provide that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `doc` variable just before you actually want to use it:

```
MergeDocument doc = null;
if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == false) 
{ 
    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDF(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID); 
} 
else if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == true) 
{ 
    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDFDriverOnly(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID); 
} 
DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly = false; 
if (doc == null)
```

Comment: In addition to your solution, to simplify things, I took the code from generatePDFDriverOnly and posted it in generatePDF's code with the FlagDriverPrintOnly flag

Comment: That got me around any additional errors as well as simplified the code.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way. Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string id, type, UniqueColID;
        string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~").ToString();
        type = Request.QueryString["type"];

        if (type.Equals("template"))
        {
            MergeDocument template = new MergeDocument(FilePath + @"\Template\MVCTemplate.pdf");
            template.DrawToWeb();
        }
        else
        {
            id = Request.QueryString["id"];
            UniqueColID = DBFunctions.DBFunctions.testExist(id);
            MergeDocument doc;
            if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == false)
            {
               doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDF(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
            }
            else if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == true)
            {
                doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDFDriverOnly(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
            }
            DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly = false;
                if (doc == null)
                doc = new MergeDocument(FilePath + @"\Template\MVCTemplate.pdf");

            doc.DrawToWeb();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox("Creating PDF file was not successful. " + err.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the `doc` declaration and assignment, and put the declaration in appropriate scope:

```
MergeDocument doc = null;

if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == false)
{
    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDF(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
}
else if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == true)
{
    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDFDriverOnly(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
}

// Use the `doc` below as appropriate...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Refactor the code.**

Extract the creation of the object to a new method. This way the flow of your program is more clear.

Uninitialized or variables that just retain their default value are bad. The compiler wont be able to catch any misuse of an unassigned variable (because it's default value is now null).

Basically:

```
var doc = GetMergeDocument(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID)
if (doc == null)
    doc = new MergeDocument(FilePath + @"\Template\MVCTemplate.pdf");

doc.DrawToWeb();
```

This way we can also tell that if `GetMergeDocument` returned null we would handle that accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is fairly simple.  I'll assume you're new to c#.  Just move the `doc` variable to a wider scope:

```
MergeDocument doc = null;
if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == false)
{
    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDF(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
}
else if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == true)
{
    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDFDriverOnly(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare it prior to entering the if.

The declaration is this line:

```
 MergeDocument doc;
```

Then assign it wherever you need

```
doc = PDF ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this declaration of `doc` variable to the top of the function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        MergeDocument doc // Move the declaration here..
        try 
        { 
            string id, type, UniqueColID; 
            string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~").ToString(); 
            type = Request.QueryString["type"]; 

            if (type.Equals("template")) 
            { 
                MergeDocument template = new MergeDocument(FilePath + @"\Template\MVCTemplate.pdf"); 
                template.DrawToWeb(); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                id = Request.QueryString["id"]; 
                UniqueColID = DBFunctions.DBFunctions.testExist(id); 
                if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == false) 
                { 
                    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDF(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID); 
                } 
                else if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == true) 
                { 
                    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDFDriverOnly(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID); 
                } 
                DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly = false; 
                    if (doc == null) 
                    doc = new MergeDocument(FilePath + @"\Template\MVCTemplate.pdf"); 

                doc.DrawToWeb(); 
            } 
        } 
        catch(Exception err) 
        { 
            MessageBox("Creating PDF file was not successful. " + err.ToString()); 
        }
```

Comment: That's too much, variable shouldn't leave the "else" block.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define `MergeDocument` either outside of the `try` statement or within the `else` statement in order to use it outside of the `if...else if` statement.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    MergeDocument doc = null;
        try
        {
            string id, type, UniqueColID;
            string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~").ToString();
            type = Request.QueryString["type"];

            if (type.Equals("template"))
            {
                MergeDocument template = new MergeDocument(FilePath + @"\Template\MVCTemplate.pdf");
                template.DrawToWeb();
            }
            else
            {
                id = Request.QueryString["id"];
                UniqueColID = DBFunctions.DBFunctions.testExist(id);
                if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == false)
                {
                    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDF(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
                }
                else if (DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly == true)
                {
                    doc = PDF.LongFormManipulation.generatePDFDriverOnly(id, type, FilePath, UniqueColID);
                }
                DBFunctions.DBFunctions.FlagDriverPrintOnly = false;
                    if (doc == null)
                    doc = new MergeDocument(FilePath + @"\Template\MVCTemplate.pdf");

                doc.DrawToWeb();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox("Creating PDF file was not successful. " + err.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote a perfect valid question I would appreciate you leave a comment